# Complex Rendering in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

For about a week now I have been trying to get a view to render. I have an application that needs to be able to export collections so I decided to use a line partial that renders as a `.txt` and `.csv` in the web browser. So far so good in terms of getting the entire collection to render (line by line). However, I am having trouble getting certain collection objects (in this case products) to duplicate themselves based on a certain attribute (size element).

The code below is kind of where I am stuck at now

#### Controller

```
class PexportController < ApplicationController
  layout 'csv'

  def index
  end

  def show
    @feed_template = params[:id]
    @products = Product.find :all
    @products.each do |product|
      unless product.size.nil? || product.size.empty? || product.size.kind_of?(Fixnum)
        @products << new_products_for(product)
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.text
    end
  end

  private

  def new_products_for(product = {})
    products = Array.new
    product.size.each do |p|
      products << Product.new(p.attributes)
    end
    products
  end
end
```

View

```
<%= render partial: 'pexport/p', collection: @products %>
```

Partial

```
<%= p.sku %>  <%= p.name %> <%= p.price %> ......
```

I basically just need to get the controller method to work. The attribute :size that I am using for the line duplicator is simply an array like so `[1,2,3]`. And I would like products that contain this size attribute to duplicate themselves based on the number of sizes in their size array. I am not even sure if I am going about it the right away but it has gotten to that point where I am going in circles so I figured I would post it.

Comment: Your `unless` statement is rather odd, since if it is a `Fixnum`, it will throw a `NoMethodError` before it gets to the check if it is, since `Fixnum` does not have `empty?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative answer: is there some reason you need to duplicate the entire object in the controller? You could simplify things by just doing something like this in your view:

```
<% if p.size.is_a?(Array) %>
  <% p.size.each do |s| %>
    <%= p.sku %>  <%= p.name %> <%= p.price %> <%= s %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= p.sku %>  <%= p.name %> <%= p.price %> <%= p.size %>
<% end %>
```

Or something to that effect.

Comment: This is the route I originally took just couldn't get it to play nice. Can I replace the "<%= p.sku %>  <%= p.name %> <%= p.price %> <%= s %>" and "<%= p.sku %>  <%= p.name %> <%= p.price %> <%= p.size %>" with two different partials?.........ie. <%= render partial: 'feeds/pwithsizes', collection: /@products %> and <%= render partial: 'feeds/pnosizes', collection: /@products %>

Comment: I suppose so, though it seems like repeating code unnecessarily. It would really help to have more detail in your question, and perhaps a little more context about what it is you want to do (e.g. why the size attribute is an array, and why that means you need to duplicate products for it).

Comment: For some data feed formats, product options (in this case size) must have their own line in a csv or txt output. So say you have product xyz with sizes 1,2,3. The output of the feed must be something like |row 1| product xyz size 1 |row 2| product xyz size 2 |row 3| product xyz size 3.....and the feed would continually iterate over all products, duplicating itself if it contained any values in the size attribute array. In terms of context, when I say feed I am referring to 3rd party channels such as google, amazon, ebay, etc.

Comment: Addtionally I have a show.text.erb file with <%= render partial: "feeds/#{@feed_template}" %> to separate the various feeds....so for example _amazon.text.erb would have all of the amazon feed headers and _p.text.erb (the line partial) would have all the variables that belong in the columns of those headers

Comment: I took a step back, stopped over complicating things and stuck your code between <% @products.each do |product| %> and <% end %>..Worked like a charm. Many thanks for your help and patience. Have a great holiday weekend!

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it. With that done, hopefully you'll be able to enjoy the long weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're doing, you have a list of products, but some of those product entries should be displayed as more than one product if they have more than one size. Assuming that's correct, your logic is a bit off: `new_products_for` is returning an array which is being added as a **single element** at the end of your `@products` array. So your partial won't know how to deal with it. You could try something like this:

```
@my_products = Product.find :all
@products = []
@my_products.each do |p|
  if p.size.blank? || p.size.kind_of?(Fixnum)
    @products << p 
  else
    @products += new_products_for(p)
  end
end
```

Also, I suggest you make the `Product.new` line more explicit:

```
products << Product.new(:sku => p.sku, :name => p.name, ...)
```

`p.attributes` will give you **all** the attributes of the model, including `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at` which may interfere with what you're doing.

Comment: Many thanks for the insight and quick reply. I forgot to mention that I had another view file <% [my_product.name, my_product.sku, my_product.price].each_with_index do |attribute, index| %>"<%= attribute %>"<%= "," unless (index % 2).eql?(0) && !index.eql?(0) %><% end %>....I think that covers that Product.new line you were mentioning?

Comment: Basically there are roughly 200 attributes so I made a template with the headers and then there is a partial within that for each line

Comment: You're new to ruby, hey? As you learn the language, you'll find a lot of neat details that will help you simplify your code. E.g. that entire view could just be done with `<%= [my_product.name, my_product.sku, my_product.price].join(", ") %>`.

Comment: Yea, only about 5-6 months in. Thanks for noticing =) lol...However I did try something similar to your example view but was running into issues as I have multiple export templates that need to be rendered in multiple formats (some products even needing different headers, category specific formatting). That last line I sent was a patch for an issue I was having with the tab delimited txt view.

Comment: Ok, I think you need to add more detail to your question. It's hard to help without all the information.